# autodesk or any other api to convert dwg to json

Tags: json, autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-designautomation

I would like to know if there is an API to convert Dwg to Json so that I can process in web application, not for rendering the CAD file.

Comment: Please, describre what you tried and what kind of researches you did before asking. Also, specify what kind of API you need, free or not, protocol type, etc. Seems there are some alternatives for online conversion and also paid conversion API.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer) a code sample with a plugin to extract data to JSON from drawings - that's part of a demo for the Forge [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page/) API (that's cloud base service/API for automation here though so not sure if this API itself fits the bill for you) but you can just use the [plugins](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer/tree/master/src) on your local installation alone if you want.

Comment: if he's are looking to extract common metadata [Model Derivative](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview/) API could also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about DXF? It is text, it is documented.